# How can we default the number of partitions after Union in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there spark conf property available to default the number of partitions after UnionAll operation in Spark.. In case joins and aggregations, spark.sql.shuffle.partitions value is used as default partition size and do we have similar property to restrict the number of partitions after UnionAll operation.. The problem which I see now is if I join dataframe df1 to df2, the number of resulting partition is df1.partitions + df2.partitions and I am looking for a solution to restrict the number of resulting partitions of all unions in my program..

Comment: Which programming language are you using ?

Comment: Scala programming language